# Cannot connect to remote SQL Server on laptop

Tags: sql-server-2012, remote-connection

When trying to connect to a remote SQL Server 2012 database from Management Studio 2012 on my laptop, I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:53). the network path was not found.

I hosted my website on Host Gator hosting provider and I have created a database on their hosting server with user details. I am trying to connect to the remote database using my laptop. I have windows 10 operating system on my laptop.

Below are the steps I have followed:

1. Make sure that the TCP/IP and Named Pipes protocols are enabled in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Make sure that the SQL Server Browser and the SQL Server is up and running on my machine
3. Make sure that the TCP/IP protocol with port number:1433 is added to inbound rules in the firewall.
4. Make sure that TCP/IP protocol is enabled through CLIConfg

Comment: @charan tej : I approved your edit. I'd like to point out that things like "Thanks in advance" are considered noise on Stack Overflow. They should be removed from posts, not added.

Answer (score 0):

## Windows Shared

You will need to whitelist your IP on the server if you want to remotely manage your databases with software such as Microsoft Server Management Studio Express.

1. Login to Plesk.
2. Click Websites & Domains tab at the top.
3. Click SQL Whitelist icon (last icon seen, SQL Whitelist - BETA on some servers).
4. Click Add IP, select service and type IP; Click OK.

-or-

Click Add my IP then select service.
Note: You must input an IP address. Plesk does not allow for wildcard whitelisting. If you have a dynamic IP address that changes periodically, you will need to re-whitelist your IP every time your IP changes.

How can I find out my computers IP address?

Simple, just go to hostgator.com/ip.shtml

I enabled remote access, now what?

Please allow up to one hour for the whitelist to be applied to the firewall.

## Windows Dedicated

1. Log into RDP (remote desktop).
2. Go to Start.
3. Select Administrative Tools.
4. Click on Windows Firewall With Advanced Security.
5. Click on Inbound Rules on the left-hand side.
6. In the middle, click on MSSQL Server or MySQL.
7. Under the MSSQL Server section, click Properties.
8. Click the Scope tab.
9. At the bottom, under Remote IP Address, click Add and add your IP.

To find your computer's IP address, just go to hostgator.com/ip.shtml
Click OK.
[image: Image View]

Comment: I cannot find Whitelist icon in my host gator login

Comment: Is your panel is windows shared or windows dedicated. Above provided for Windows shared steps.